# my mongodb shows as 0.000gb even after inserting the data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb.I have installed mongodb 3.2
After installing i inserted a record,which says inserted successfully.But my db is shown as 0.000gb.
Please find the screen shot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVGbt.jpg)

Comment: That's strange. In my case MongoDB allocates 0.078GB by default for each database I have. Which storage engine are you using?

Comment: This is normal for the [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/wiredtiger/) storage engine, since it does not [preallocate files as MMAPv1 does](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#preallocated-data-files). So unless you have at least 1MB of data, the size is shown as 0.000Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiredTiger stores newly inserted data in its Journal file called WiredTigerLog. Data from the journal is moved to the actual collection file every 60 sec or 2gb of data written whichever happens first but it has a minimum data limit which under WiredTiger will not move docs from the journal to the collection file itself no matter how much time will pass. For an example if you insert a small document the collection size will not grow but eventually if you insert that document again multiple times you will see the collection size increase at a certain second next minute.